# My global exception handler is not catching all exceptions

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I am using Web Api and am trying to create a global exception handler.

I've created the following handler, however some exceptions it doesn't catch. I've put a break point in at the `Handle` method and it doesn't even get called. I'm guessing something inside of Web API is catching the exception first.

For example, the below was created. I want to catch this exception so that I can return it in the format that the rest of my API adheres to:

`{
    "Message": "The request is invalid.",
    "MessageDetail": "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'personId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult GetPersonById(System.String, Int32)' in 'Pasco.Middleware.WebApi.Controllers.PersonController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter."
}`

My `Global.asax`:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new WebApiCoreExceptionHandler());
```

My Handler (snipped):

```
public class WebApiCoreExceptionHandler : ExceptionHandler
{
    private static ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(WebApiCoreExceptionHandler));

    public override void Handle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You are implementing Web API 2 functionality in ASP.NET 4, correct? Have you tried creating an ExceptionLogger that handles and lets you examine all exceptions? Maybe that lets you gain some insight. And as far as I know there's a HandleAsync method on the ExceptionHandler class. Have you tried overriding that one aswell?

Comment: @FunkyPeanut Web API 2 with MVC 5. I tried both of those and none of those bits of code are being called when setting breakpoints.

Comment: Did you try with an ExceptionFilterAttribute?